# How I can validate fields on forms on identity fields in form. Django

Tags: django, forms, validation

How I can validate fields on forms on identity fields in form instantly without POST request?

my fields in model:

```
password = models.CharField(max_length=45, verbose_name="")
password2 = models.CharField(max_length=45, verbose_name="")
```

and my fields in form:

```
'password': widgets.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'New Password'}),
'password2': widgets.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Re-Entere Password'}),
```

This is the code I tried:

```
def clean_password(self):
password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
if not password2:
    raise forms.ValidationError("You must confirm your password")
if password1 != password2:
    raise forms.ValidationError("Your passwords do not match")
return password2
```

Code in view:

```
def saves_data_user_on_registration (request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        c = {}
        c.update(csrf(request))
        form_user_data = Form_registration(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form_user_data.is_valid():
            print form_user_data.errors
            form_user_data.save()
            return render_to_response('see_you_later.html', c, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        else:
            print form_user_data.errors
            return render_to_response('error.html', c, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: I don't understand what it is you exactly want.

Comment: I want verify fields on identity (that fields were equal). But do this without POST request

Comment: What did you try that didn't work?

Comment: I'm new in Django. I try only one (code in form):

Comment: No errors. Nothing to happens.

Comment: You need to provide more information, like how you are sending the request back to your view code.

Comment: in view I'm only saves data in form

Answer (score 0):

I you want to access two fields during validation you need to use `clean()` not `clean_myfield()`.

Check the docs.

What do you mean with "without a POST request?".

I would never accept passwords via GET. HTTP GET requests get stored in proxies and caches!

Comment: >What do you mean with "without a POST request?".

Comment: >What do you mean with "without a POST request?". - I don't want't to press the button in html (<input type="submit") that happened chek for my two fields

Comment: Do you want to validate the form, if it was not submitted? I think you don't want it. Check if data was submitted before you call `form.is_valid()`. If not data was sent, don't validate the form.